# preg_split without delete search pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have a some thousands text file to parse, it's a product catalog that follows a certain pattern.

It has two serial numbers, with one of them I was splitting the whole text into an array, each key a product.

The problem is the serial I was using in preg_split gets deleted from the product, and I need it.

Here's a raw product:

```
1532.000028-01532.213.00010875-8
TRES ANÉIS, DOIS PENDENTES, DOIS BRINCOS, SENDO UM 
COM 
TARRACHA DE METAL NÃO NOBRE, DE: OURO, OURO BRANCO BAIXO; 
CONTÉM: diamantes, pérola cultivada, pedra, massa; CONSTAM: amassada(s), 
incompleta(s), PESO LOTE: 13,50G (TREZE GRAMAS E CI NQUENTAR$ 901,00
Valor Grama: 66,74
```

The first numbers are the two serials, they are stick together beacuse of flaws of the PDF parser.

Here's the REGEX I'm using to split the array into products:

```
$texto = preg_split("/([0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{6}[-][0-9]{1})+/",$texto);
```

Output:

```
1532.213.00010875-8
TRES ANÉIS, DOIS PENDENTES, DOIS BRINCOS, SENDO UM 
COM 
TARRACHA DE METAL NÃO NOBRE, DE: OURO, OURO BRANCO BAIXO; 
CONTÉM: diamantes, pérola cultivada, pedra, massa; CONSTAM: amassada(s), 
incompleta(s), PESO LOTE: 13,50G (TREZE GRAMAS E CI NQUENTAR$ 901,00
Valor Grama: 66,74
```

As you can see, the first serial is removed from the output. I need it. How can I split these products, keeping both arrays?

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: It should keep both serials, made a bin to exemplify: https://pastee.org/7k7ex (pastebin was offline)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your capture group into a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), like this:

```
$texto = preg_split("/(?=[0-9]{4}[.][0-9]{6}[-][0-9]{1})/",$texto);
```

Comment: Next time you should be more specific on the output you expect.

Comment: @hwnd I'll remember that